# What are the alternatives to front loading of jobs/tasks/projects?

Tags: job-shop-scheduling

When assigning jobs (or tasks or projects) to a starting time, with a ready and due time for each job, there are different scenarios:

- A) **Front loading**: Assign all jobs as soon as possible. As close as possible to their ready time. For example, we need build 5 red cars before the end of year, so we could them now in October or wait until November or December. With Front loading, we'll build them now in October, unless there's a more urgent order (for example to build blue cars this month), which would push them out to November.
- B) Assign all jobs on their ideal execution time. For example, we need to clean a house once every 7 days. We cleaned it yesterday. We could clean it again today, but that will just mean we have to clean it sooner next week. Ideally, we wait 6 days (no more, no less) to clean it. But it's fine if there's sometimes a few more or less days between the cleaning, due to other more priority jobs.
- C) *Back loading?*: Assign all jobs as late as possible. As close as possible to their due time.

What the canonical terminology for B) and C)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scheduling literature, there are some concepts to define a sequence/schedule plan. Optimal, non-delay, active, and semi-active schedule. W.r.t this and how you would change a sequence into a schedule, also, there are some rules so-called [dispatching rules](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/dispatching-rule).

Indeed, what you are looking for sounds like, forward scheduling, JIT scheduling, and backward scheduling respectively.

For more details: Scheduling: Theory, Algorithms, and system by Pinedo, Michael L.

Comment: Interesting, "front loading" (from timetabling literature, for example for exam scheduling) and "forward scheduling" (from scheduling literature) are clearly the same thing indeed.

Comment: The second one isn't really JIT scheduling, I'd argue though. If you want to clean your house every 7 days, making the next sunday the ideal date, then cleaning it a day late doesn't make it over time (it's still in time, just not ideal).

Comment: Specifically for maintenance scheduling, JIT scheduling is common for highly regulated sectors (airplanes), because being over time bans the use of the airplane. But for maintenance scheduling of elevators, roads or railroads, the maintenance isn't aiming to be Just In Time: it's aiming to be as close as possible to the Ideal Time (and a scheduling it later has a soft impact, just like scheduling it too soon). Wdyt?

Comment: What's the difference between JIT scheduling and backwards scheduling?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet My understanding is that JIT is based on a due date (or, for sequences of tasks, the final due date backtracked by the processing times of the remaining steps). If you are going to allow housekeeping to be *approximately* once a week (maybe less), I'm not sure you have a firm enough due date to call the wait six (or so) days JIT. At least as originally envisioned, JIT would require more precision than that.

Comment: Typically, I am working with maintenance jobs that have a ready date, a due date, but also an ideal date (between those 2 other dates). The ready and due dates are hard, the ideal date is soft. Does that make sense? This is especially the case for machines for which the risk of failure increases if maintenance is neglected ("Either you plan for maintenance or maintenance plans it for you.")

Comment: @Geoffrey, I am happy that the answer would be useful. As the result of the schedule plan heavily depends on how the objective function would be determined the difference between the objective functions comes from that. Suppose, in some cases, earliness wouldn't be allowed, in the other cases tardiness/lateness wouldn't be allowed, and in another, neither earliness nor  tardiness will not be accepted. These situations referred to forward, backward, and JIT scheduling respectively.

Comment: In the literature, the term "due date" is used when it is soft. Otherwise, the term "deadline" is used. Some problems have jobs with both due dates and deadlines. For example https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cie.2019.106102

Comment: @fontanf, thanks for your comment. As far as I see, the due date is frequently used in the shop floor or detailed scheduled environments. In comparison, the deadline is frequently used in project planning or something like this. By the way, as you mentioned too, the difference comes from literature than practical. :)